# Add onmouseover event in links rendered in C#.net webbrowser control

Tags: c#, ihtmldocument2

My task is to highlight selected words rendered in html in webbrowser control of C#.net. I accomplish it by using IHtmldocument2. (ref: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/02/13/highlight-words-in-webbrowser-control/).
Now, my next task is when i mouseover on the highlighted text, a custom popup will appear to show some information about that highlighted text. It serves like a tooltip. How can i do this? can you give me some sample codes?

Help Please

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

what i did with this is just create a div and insert it in the body section. i created a javascript that sets the position property of that div to absolute and with just simple coordinates, i set the top and left property of the div to the position of the element being hover on.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest [jQuery](http://www.jquery.com) here are some tutorials for popups http://speckyboy.com/2009/09/16/25-useful-jquery-tooltip-plugins-and-tutorials/. In the control/function that highlight the words you should be able to set the attributes needed for jQuery to show popups.

Comment: I need to implement it in winforms.